# Give users lives and gender

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm pretty new to javascript/dom scripting and I'm doing small projects to get better. My idea was a Truth or Dare'ish game where you can add as many users as you want, after that the users will get added to this Winwheel: 
"https://github.com/zarocknz/javascript-winwheel". Then you spin the wheel and you get "x player has to this".

My first thought was to add all users to an array, but my problem is I want all players to have a health system if you want to skip your turn, and every user has f.eg 3 lives. and I also want to store if the user is a boy or a girl. How can I Store info as lives for each individual, and gender when all the users are stored in an array?

Comment: You do it the same way as without an array.

Comment: Care to elaborate?

Comment: @Tweey Each user could be represented by a standard JavaScript object, then you just add the objects to the list. I believe melpomene meant that the representation of the users is completely separate from how the users are stored. One doesn't effect the other.

Answer (score 0):

You could store an array of objects! Each object would represent a user.
So you could have a user object with this schema:

```
{
    name: 'John',
    lives: 3,
    gender: 'male'
}
```

And you could keep adding as many properties as you want.

Then you could push those items to an array. It would look like this:

```
[
    {
        name: 'John',
        lives: 3,
        gender: 'male'
    },
    {
        name: 'Vanessa',
        lives: 2,
        gender: 'female'
    },
    ...
]
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I haven't used OOP much before but I will try. Thank you very much!